# How to make a \newcommand to add +1 to an expression involving symbolic and numeric parts?

Tags: macros

The function should output `\alpha+2` for an input of `\alpha+1` but I haven't been able to add +1 to the numeric part of the input without messing around with the symbolic part. So far, i have something like this:

`\newcommand{func}[1]{#1+1}`

`func[\alpha+1]`

`>>\alpha+1+1`

Comment: Distinguishing the symbolic from the numeric seems like it would be hard.  Should `\func{\alpha+1+1}` become `\alpha+1+2` or `\alpha+3`?  Should `\func{1}` become `2`?  What should happen to `\func{\alpha-1}`?  Or are you not calling your macro in those ways?

Comment: Please clarify how your query is related to TeX.LaTeX, and friends.

Comment: Yes, @Teepeemm, `\func{\alpha+1+1}` should give `\alpha+3`. Now, for the cases where either the input does not have a symbolic part (as in `func{1}`) or the output is just symbolic (as in `func{\alpha-1}`), I don't really need to call the macro for instances like that.

Comment: Sometimes you write `func` without backslash, sometimes you write `\func` with backslash. Be that as it may. The tools implemented in LaTeX to compute mathematical expressions are in no way close to a good CAS - I don't know of any LaTeX package that allows you to simplify arbitrary mathematical terms that contain variables that have no specific numerical values assigned to them.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N\l_func_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn\func#1{
\regex_extract_once:nnNTF
{^(.*[\+]\ *)?(\d+)\ *$}
{#1}
\l_func_seq
{ 
\seq_item:Nn\l_func_seq{2}
\int_eval:n{\seq_item:Nn\l_func_seq{3}+1}
}
{#1+1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\test[1]{#1 :\quad \func{#1}}

\begin{document}

\test{3}

\test{42}

\test{-3}

\test{x}

\test{x+2}

\test{x+22}

\end{document}
```

This does not really interpret expressions but tries to be safe so -3 goes to -3+1 . Basically it just numerically adds one if the expression is all digits or ends `+` followed by digits.

Answer (score 0):

This will just split the argument at the `+` (if present) and forward both to another macro that tests the two now split arguments.

This will fail when the part after `+` is not an integer number.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\NewDocumentCommand{\funcA}  { > {\SplitArgument{1}{+}} m }{\funcADo#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\funcADo}{ m m }
  {#1+\inteval{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{0}{#2}+1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\funcB}  { > {\SplitArgument{1}{+}} m }{\funcBDo#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\funcBDo}{ m m }{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \IfInteger{#1}
      {\inteval{#1+1}}
      {#1+1}%
  }{#1+\inteval{#2+1}}}

\newcommand*\test[1]{%
  \noindent\texttt{\string\funcA\{#1\}}: \funcA{#1}\\
           \texttt{\string\funcB\{#1\}}: \funcB{#1}\par\vspace{1ex}}
\begin{document}
\test{3}
\test{42}
\test{-3}
\test{+-3}
\test{4+1}
\test{x}
\test{x+2}
\test{x+22}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]